# is it possible to measure the loading time of several pages in a react.js project?

Tags: reactjs, performance, time, loading

I have used the Profiler API from react, and PerformanceNavigationTiming API, but one relies on the life cycle of the components, and the other API has the values that I need, but the properties are read-only, and I'm trying to find an alternative that gives me the metric for the pages without the need to repeat code

Comment: Why its React specific? You can open your browser dev tool and go over the page performance, for chrome you have "Performance Insights".

Comment: it's because i need a functionality that can display that data on the console everytime a load event of a page is triggered

Comment: So just use `perfromance.now`